# Remote Display iOS play a sound more than once = garbled

Tags: ios, swift, google-cast

Trying to play a sound effect everytime I press a button through Remote Display API.

Using the sample app as reference. It works fine on device, but on the TV, it sounds terrible if I try to play it more than once (and I don't have to press the button very fast to get it to be stuck)

Here is my testing (not checking for remote session errors) code to try it:

```
var loop:AEAudioFilePlayer?
var audioController:AEAudioController?
let k48kHZ:Float64 = 48000.0
let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("got_it", withExtension: "wav")!

var receiver:AEBlockAudioReceiver?

func setupSound(){

    // Temporary workaround for known issue where sound crackles on new Chromecast devices.
    let cracklingSoundWorkaroundStereo = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
        mSampleRate: k48kHZ,
        mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        mFormatFlags: kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked |
        kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved,
        mBytesPerPacket: UInt32(sizeof(Float)),
        mFramesPerPacket: 1,
        mBytesPerFrame: UInt32(sizeof(Float)),
        mChannelsPerFrame: 2,
        mBitsPerChannel: 8*UInt32(sizeof(Float)),
        mReserved: 1)

    audioController = AEAudioController(audioDescription: cracklingSoundWorkaroundStereo, options: AEAudioControllerOptionEnableOutput)


    do{
        loop?.channelIsPlaying = false
        loop?.currentTime = 0
        loop?.channelIsPlaying = true            
    } catch {
        print("Failure")
    }

    // Block the main output. Our receiver above will still receive the channel sound.
    audioController?.muteOutput = true

    // Add a new output receiver pushing to the remote display. TAEE defaults to 1024 buffers, which
    // should work for us!
    receiver = AEBlockAudioReceiver { (source, time, frames, bufferList) -> Void in
        CastController.sharedInstance.remoteSession.enqueueAudioBuffer(bufferList, frames: frames, pts: time)
    }

    audioController?.addOutputReceiver(receiver, forChannel: loop)
    //loop?.channelIsPlaying = true
}

@IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {

    do{

        loop = try AEAudioFilePlayer(URL: file)

        loop?.loop = false

        audioController?.addChannels([loop!])
        audioController?.addOutputReceiver(receiver, forChannel: loop)


    } catch {
        print("Failure")
    }

}
```

UPDATE:
Basically, it plays fine after a few seconds of playback. But if your sound effect is 4-5 seconds long, it will sound terrible >50% of the time.

Comment: What version of chromecast (hardware) are you using?

Comment: v2 (the new one). I'll test with my old V1 to see if same thing happens

Comment: Any news on the issue? Everything else is working great with Remote Display except playing sound effects.

Comment: You might want to open an issue on our SDK issue tracker with all the relevant info.